# How to edit the navigation buttons on the not generic website

Tags: html, wordpress, revolution-slider

I am running revolution slider, not generic template, on wordpress.

Does anyone know how to edit, or remove the navigation menu at the top of the screen.

Comment: It's best to add code to show people what you have tried, that way people can help you more.

Comment: **[Please add a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example along with your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: This is a better place for your question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/